# Is there a ring stacky approach to $\ell$-adic or rigid cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, etale-cohomology, stacks

Ever since Simpson's paper [Sim], it was observed that many different cohomology theories arise in the following way: we begin with our space $X$, we associate to it a stack $X_\text{stk}$ (which depends on the chosen cohomology theory), and then the cohomology of $X$ coincides with the quasi-coherent cohomology of $X_\text{stk}$.

We have even more! Very often cohomology theories come from a six-functor formalism $D(X)$ and we often have that $D(X)=D_\text{qc}(X_\text{stk})$.

As far as I know, this is known for: (Often there are many references discussing this, I put the first one that came to mind just to help the reader find something about it.)

- de Rham cohomology; [GR] (We can also recover the underlying Hodge filtration. [Bh §2.3])
- Crystalline cohomology; [RG]
- Prismatic cohomology; [Bh]
- Syntomic cohomology; [Bh]
- Dolbeault cohomology; [Sim2]
- Betti cohomology; [PS]
- Deligne cohomology (I think); [PS]

The most notable absences from this list seem to be étale / $\ell$-adic cohomology and rigid cohomology. **Is there a stacky approach to these cohomology theories as well?**

References:

[Sim] C. Simpson - [Homotopy over the complex numbers and generalized de Rham cohomology](https://www.tib.eu/en/search/id/BLCP%3ACN013382849/Homotopy-Over-the-Complex-Numbers-and-Generalized/)

[Sim2] C. Simpson - [The Hodge filtration on nonabelian cohomology](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9604005.pdf)

[Bh] B. Bhatt - [Prismatic $F$-Gauges](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Ebhatt/teaching/mat549f22/lectures.pdf)

[GR] D. Gaitsgory, N. Rozenblyum - [Crystals and D-modules](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.2087.pdf)

[RG] R. Gregoric - [The Crystalline Space and Divided Power Completion](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gregoric/CrystalMath.pdf)

[PS] M. Porta, F. Sala - [Simpson’s shapes of schemes and stacks](https://people.dm.unipi.it/sala/assets/pdf/porta_sala_shapes.pdf)

Comment: Since this post is already too big, let me explain the term *ring stack* in the title for those curious: in many cases it was remarked that it suffices to construct the stack $X_\text{stk}$ for $X=\mathbb{A}^1$. The resulting object is a "ring stack" and we have $X_\text{stk}=X\circ \mathbb{A}^1_\text{stk}$ as a functor.

Comment: I don’t understand the definition of $K_B$ in Porta–Sala but at first glance it looks like something which should have an etale homotopy counterpart.

Comment: Dear @PiotrAchinger, if I understand correctly, given a scheme $X$ of finite-type over $\mathbb{C}$, its "Betti" space $X_B$ is just the constant sheaf (of anima) equal to the topological space $X_\text{an}$. (There's more about this in [Sim] and in the end of the first chapter in Scholze's notes about six-functor formalisms.) Do you have any idea for an étale counterpart?

Comment: For $\ell$-adic cohomology there is the condensed/pyknotic shape which is a condensed space whose category of local systems gives the category of lisse $\ell$-adic sheaves, see e.g. Appendix A in https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02853.

Comment: Dear @PavelSafronov, do you know if it's possible to see this condensed shape as some sort of stack and/or if this also works for constructible sheaves?

Comment: Just like the Betti stack, you can extend it to be constant in the "algebraic" direction to obtain a condensed stack. For constructible sheaves: you have to use the exit-path category in the Betti setting or the Galois category in the $\ell$-adic setting (see Chapter 13 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03281). Note that these are not (condensed) $\infty$-groupoids, but rather (condensed) $\infty$-categories.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

First, I think the [PS] reference does not give the "correct" Betti stack. In my notes on 6 functors, I define a different stack $X_B$ such that $D_{\mathrm{qc}}(X_B)$ is equivalent to (the left-completed version of) $D(X,\mathbb Z)$, for any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. It represents the functor taking any scheme $S$ to the continuous functions from $|S|$ to $X$. The [PS] reference would only be able to see the locally constant sheaves on $X$ instead, and is effectively passing to the homotopy type instead.

Roughly speaking, a prerequisite for a stacky approach to some cohomology theory is that this cohomology theory satisfies a categorical Künneth formula: $D(X)\otimes_{D(\ast)} D(Y)\cong D(X\times Y)$. At least, $X\mapsto X_B,X_{\mathrm{dR}}$ etc. all commute with finite limits (and I think this should always be true for such stacks), and the functor $X\mapsto D_{\mathrm{qc}}(X)$ often takes fibre products to tensor products (of presentable stable $\infty$-categories). The latter may fail a little bit in general, but at least it should be "close" to being true. For example, for locally compact Hausdorff spaces it is true at least for finite-dimensional ones.

For $\ell$-adic sheaves, the categorical Künneth formula fails badly. Thus, one cannot really expect a stacky approach. However, one can (and I do) hope for a stack $X_{\ell,n}$ such that $D_{\mathrm{et}}(X,\mathbb Z/\ell^n)$ embeds fully faithfully into $D_{\mathrm{qc}}(X_{\ell,n})$.

In fact, if one assumes that $X$ lives over $\mathbb Q_\ell$, and one is allowing stacks in almost schemes, then such a thing has been defined (implicitly) through the work of Lucas Mann on $p$(=$\ell$)-adic 6 functors.

So over $\mathbb Q_\ell$, it exists, but I don't know how to descend it to $\mathbb Q$.

Edit: And for rigid cohomology, I explained a construction of such a stack in my course, I hope I will one day update the notes to include it.

Comment: Dear @PeterScholze, the paper cited by Pavel Safronov on the comments shows that the categorical Künneth formula holds for Weil sheaves. Perhaps one could construct a stack for such sheaves, then. As for rigid cohomology: while we wait for your long-dreamed chapter on ring stacks, is there some reference for it? (Or is it due to yourself?)

Comment: That is a nice paper, but it does not really show the right version of the categorical Künneth formula; it gives a fully faithful functor. And I think the case of rigid cohomology is "new", although the translation from the usual picture is rather straightforward.

Comment: I did not read the whole paper, but it seems to me that Theorem 5.2.(1) really gives an equivalence of categories. And ok! I'll be waiting for the lecture notes, then! Thanks

Comment: But that result is restricting to "small" objects; roughly, it's like only having a categorical Künneth formula for $\mathrm{Perf}$ as opposed to $D_{\mathrm{qc}}$.

Comment: Dear @PeterScholze. Does this "rigid cohomoogy stack" has nontrivial maps to $\mathbb{A}^1/\mathbb{G}_m$ ? And does one recovere Besser rigid syntimic cohomology in some way? Thanks